# How to restrict/grant read/write access to child process's memory?

Tags: security, winapi, visual-c++, win32-process

Is it possible to programmatically adjust a process's privilege so that if it creates a child process at any point later on, it will always(never) have write access to that process's memory?

I have created a dll which is loaded by two different processes. At some point in my code I create a process. I have observed that depending upon which process loads my dll, I either have `PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY` or `0` access to the child process's memory. My guess is that the loading process must have put some restrictions which result in this behaviour because I am not doing anything different for either process. I looked at the process's security information in `Process Explorer` but could not spot any difference between the two. The `hToken` value is given to me by the caller who calls my API. Is this the one causing this. How can I test to confirm if so?

```
CreateProcessAsUserW(hToken, exe, cmd_line, NULL, NULL, 
    false,
    CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT | DETACHED_PROCESS | EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT | CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB,
    NULL, NULL, 
    &si, &pi);

MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION buffer;
// 'address' is some valid address
SIZE_T num = VirtualQueryEx(pi.hProcess_handle, address,&buffer,sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)); 
if(num > 0)
{
        DWORD access = buffer.AllocationProtect;  // 0x0 or 0x80 depending on which process loads dll 
        DWORD state = buffer.State;
        DWORD type = buffer.Type;
 }
```

Comment: Try comparing the `Protect` field to the `AllocationProtect` field. I believe the zero result may occur if the requested address is not part of an allocated range of pages (ie, free).

Comment: @William Ok, will try that. But why the consistent difference between 2 processes?

Comment: I suspect that `address` isn't really "some valid address" in one of the processes. If you can share a bit more about where address is coming from, I may be able to determine more.

Answer (score 0):

The [Memory Protection Constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-protection-constants) for each page of memory has nothing to do with handles, inherited or not.

Calling VirtualQuery requires certain [process access rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights), if you don't have them then VirtualQueryEx will fail.

0 is not a valid value for AllocationProtect, therefore I believe the source of your problem is the VirtualQuery failing either because the address is wrong or because you do not have the required process access right.