# How to restrict network access of a child process in windows

Tags: c#, windows, process, sandbox

I am running a child process in my C# console app using Process.Start() method. I would like to restrict the child process so that it does not have access to network.

More specifically, I am trying to run some tests by running vstest.console.exe using Process.Start(). The goal is that these tests shouldn't be accessing any slow or unreliable resources like network, database, etc. Any tests trying to talk over network should fail.

I searched on web and stackoverflow, but the closest match I got was this [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932599/how-to-restrict-grant-read-write-access-to-child-processs-memory). Any ideas?

Comment: Basically, you can't. Why do you need this?

Comment: You may create a user with restricted permissions and [Start the Process as another user](http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/startprocessasuser)

Comment: @Graffito Thanks. Running process as another user might work, but how to restrict permission for the user to not be able to access network?

Comment: In admin mode, open filer explorer, right click on the network drive and select the securiy tab of properties window. Remove the acccess rights for the new user.

Comment: @Graffito: Could this be done in code? I also tried this manually. In windows 8 (and windows 10), right click -> Properties ends up opening control panel and not the kind of dialog that you would normally see for files and folders. So, there is no security tab. In the control panel dialog that opens, I couldn't find a way to restrict access.

Comment: I have only Windows 7 at the office. So i can't help. However, try this (not sure you can change permissions) : go to Control Panel and then to “System and Security > Administrative Tools”. 
Here you will find several shortcuts including one named “Computer Management”. See what you can do with "Shared" item.